# error in jquery.ajax() CSRFToken post call phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, token, csrf

Hi
 im Trying to post an ajax call. Im using Phonegap 2.8.0, jqm 1.3.2 and Xcode  here is my code

```
window.SavePhoto= function() {

    try{ 
        var txtComment = $('#txtComment').val();
        var cameraImage = $('#cameraImage').attr('src');  
        var request_url = sessionStorage.getItem('CategoryLink');
       var X_CSRFToken = sessionStorage.getItem("X_CSRFToken");

        console.log('token=' + X_CSRFToken);
        console.log('cameraImage==' + cameraImage);        
        console.log("request_url==" + request_url);  
        console.log('txtComment==' + txtComment);

        if(!cameraImage){
            alert('Cannot save without select image','Image Required', 'Ok');            
            return;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: request_url ,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'multipart/form-data', 
            data:{"comment":txtComment,"photo_file":cameraImage}, 
            headers: {Cookie:cookie_saved,'X-CSRF-Token': X_CSRFToken}, 
            success: function (result,status,xhr) {
                if (! status.success) { 

                } else { 
                }
                alert ('message=' + JSON.stringify(status));
            },
            error: function (xhr,status,error)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });

    }

    catch(e){alert(e);}
    console.log('save photo function exit');

}
```

Phonegap application crashes before success function occurs  and give me following log. After analyzing  found out that i maybe giving invalid CSRFToken.

```
2013-11-05 16:44:20.239 Appname[5388:a0b] Suid token=b1d950c3-2d82-48f2-9867-b4bcc0c4ae08
2013-11-05 16:44:20.240 Appname[5388:a0b] cameraImage==assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=B859F94D-B670-4251-9A4A-C14ACCC8CDD1&ext=JPG
2013-11-05 16:44:20.240 Appname[5388:a0b] request_url==http://jdev104p.jalf.com/rest/users/42547/photos/albums/messages
2013-11-05 16:44:20.240 Appname[5388:a0b] txtComment==dfs


    2013-11-05 16:44:20.241 Appname[5388:a0b] -[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb364d70
    2013-11-05 16:44:20.244 Appname[5388:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb364d70'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x001725e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x030c28b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x0020f903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x0016290b ___forwarding___ + 1019
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x001624ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
        5   Foundation                          0x019b1b2d -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:] + 39
        6   Foundation                          0x019b279a -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:attributes:] + 293
        7   UIKit                               0x00585116 -[UILabel _setText:] + 97
        8   UIKit                               0x005852d4 -[UILabel setText:] + 40
        9   UIKit                               0x008b26aa -[UIAlertView(Private) setBodyText:] + 74
        10  UIKit                               0x008bdde6 -[UIAlertView setMessage:] + 40
        11  UIKit                               0x008be45e -[UIAlertView initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:] + 134
        12  Appname                           0x00027be6 -[CDVNotification showDialogWithMessage:title:buttons:defaultText:callbackId:dialogType:] + 342
        13  Appname                           0x00028016 -[CDVNotification alert:] + 406
        14  Appname                           0x0006bb2c -[CDVCommandQueue execute:] + 1132
        15  Appname                           0x0006b25b -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] + 683
        16  Appname                           0x0006ada9 -[CDVCommandQueue enqueCommandBatch:] + 153
        17  Appname                           0x0006af56 -[CDVCommandQueue fetchCommandsFromJs] + 182
        18  Appname                           0x0006ae6f -[CDVCommandQueue maybeFetchCommandsFromJs:] + 159
        19  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x030d481f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
        20  Foundation                          0x019c1c18 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 285
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x000fb8af __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
        22  CoreFoundation                      0x000fb23b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
        23  CoreFoundation                      0x0011830e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
        24  CoreFoundation                      0x00117b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
        25  CoreFoundation                      0x0011794b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        26  GraphicsServices                    0x045109d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
        27  GraphicsServices                    0x045107fe GSEventRun + 104
        28  UIKit                               0x003d894b UIApplicationMain + 1225
        29  Appname                           0x000029d6 main + 134
        30  Appname                           0x00002945 start + 53
        31  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours i found this working. One thing is clear we cannot upload  photo through Ajax Jquery. We have to use filetransfer plugin. here is my working code. Another thing we have to use cordova 2.9.0 instead of cordova 2.8.0 because There is a bug in camera getpicture FILE_URI

```
window.SavePhoto= function() {

    try{ 
        var txtComment = document.getElementById('txtComments');
        var cameraImage = $('#cameraImage').attr('src');  
        var request_url = sessionStorage.getItem('CategoryLink');
        var X_CSRFToken = sessionStorage.getItem('X_CSRFToken');
        var cookies= X_CSRFToken;
        var lblpath = document.getElementById('lblpath');
        var fileURI= lblpath.innerHTML;



        if(!cameraImage){
            msgAlert('Cannot save without select image','Image Required', 'Ok');            
            return;
        }  

        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "photo_file";
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        options.chunkedMode = false; 
        options.fileName=    fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.params = {
            'comment': txtComment.value 
        };
        options.headers = {
            //'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken,
            Cookie: cookies
        }; 
       console.log('options=' + JSON.stringify( options));
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI(request_url), win, fail, options); 
    } 
    catch(e)
    {
        msgAlert(e);
    }
    console.log('save photo exit');

}
var win=function (r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

var fail=function (error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}
```